# AD Change Webpage field using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am currently trying to figure out how to change the web page field in Active Directory using Powershell for every user in AD.

Example I have is Set-ADUser -HomePage https://google.com/ -Identity username

Will this do everyone in AD?

I need to know if there is anything else I need in the script to do all users

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get all users from AD and pipe it to Set-ADUser. However be careful as this will immediately overwrite that field for every AD User in your AD.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | Set-ADUser -HomePage "https://google.com/"
```

To set it only for users where there field is currently empty

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "HomePage -notlike '*'" | Set-ADUser -HomePage "https://google.com/"
```

Comment: Thanks David. So what I am now doing is getting the users that have a certain webpage in that field already and changing it. That is not a problem. However I am struggling to find a way to get all user where that field is blank and then add the website address

Answer (score 0):

Get-ADUser -Filter * | Set-ADUser -HomePage "https:// website /"

Oct2023: Thanks. This worked a treat in AD, Windows server 2012.
-dave